# Laravel pagination with orderByRaw doesnt work

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I need to order my results by the enum field. This field, called status can be either open, close, or edit. Now, I want to get all the entries, with edit, then open, and finally close order.
this is my code:

```
Survey::orderByRaw("case status when 'edit' then 1 when 'open' then 2 when 'close' then 3 end")->paginate(20);
```

The problem is that some values are repeated when the page is changed. does anyone have a solution to this issue? or does he know where the problem comes from?

Comment: In short, you need to add sort by primary key. Cause database dont know anything about your pagination and return rows it's more easy to get.

Comment: @SiZE

Thank you for your help, did you mean like this?


` Survey::orderByRaw("case status ...")->orderBy('id)->paginate(20)`

Comment: @mohhamed hossein yes

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment, I changed the code as follows and the problem was fixed

`Survey::orderByRaw("case status when 'edit' then 1 when 'open' then 2 when 'close' then 3 end")->orderBy('id')->paginate(20)`;